# Making fopen() open files from a certain directory

Tags: c, shell

I have a function with something like

```cpp
FILE *file1 = fopen("testing.txt", "r");
```

I can't modify this line. However, if I make a file named "testing.txt" in, say `/tmp`, would I be able to make the function load the file from `/tmp` instead of it's own directory. (Maybe by modifying the `PATH` variable?)

Comment: This depends on your OS. C by itself has no notion of directory. In a POSIXish system there's normally no way to do this.

Comment: You can call `fopen("mycertaindir\\testing.txt", "r");` (on Windows) or `fopen("mycertaindir/testing.txt", "r");` on Linux/Unix/Mac etc. Please tell us more what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelWalz You would need to quote the backslash on Windows. Alternatively use forward slashes.

Comment: I'm using Linux, and I, can't modify the C code itself. I need to do it via terminal.

Comment: The PATH variable is used to search executable programs. Here you just have to change your current directory. See Jonathon Reinhart's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the program doesn't change its own working directory, you could `cd` into `/tmp` and simply run the program from there.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ /absolute/path/to/my_program
```

Answer (score 1):

That opens a file from your current working directory.

You can change the current working directory using [`chdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chdir.html).

Comment: I'm using the terminal, so is there an equivalent for it? ( I need to change the directory without C code)

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547440/opening-file-in-another-directory-in-c).

This is using `C` code.

You can also use [`cd`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucd.htm).

For example, go to the terminal:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ cd /path_to_your_program
```

Also, `cd ..` will make you go to the directory above, and `cd` will make you go to the home directory.

Also, if you do not have the program in the directory in which you have to compile it, you can use `cp` which copies file.

```
$ cp /path_to_copy_from /path_to_copy_to
```

Then you can go to that directory, and run it from there.

I would recommend you to take a basic linux tutorial like [this](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/).